Ignoring a base type in Entity Framework Core 9 code-first
I typically use the following interfaces for EF Core entities (.NET 9, EF Core 9):
public interface IEntity
    where TEntity: class, new()
{
    // Identity column.
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsAuditable { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTimeCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateTimeModified { get; set; }
}

public interface IEntity<TEntity>:
    IEntity
    where TEntity: class, IEntity, IEntity<TEntity>, new()
{ }

I am now considering using concrete base classes for all entities.
Consider the following hierarchy:
// Acts as a based class for all entities in the DbContext.
public class EntityBase<TEntity>:
    IEntity<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class, IEntity, IEntity<TEntity>, new()
{
    // Identity column.
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsAuditable { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTimeCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateTimeModified { get; set; }
}

public class DocumentBase : EntityBase<DocumentBase>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ElementBase : EntityBase<ElementBase>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// Should represent a database table with all properties
// from the base class but without a discriminator column.
public class Document : DocumentBase
{
    public virtual ICollection<Element> Elements { get; set; } = [];
}

// Should represent a database table with all properties
// from the base class but without a discriminator column.
public class Element : ElementBase
{
    public long DocumentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Document Document { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Document> Documents { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Element> Elements { get; set; }
}

A couple of things to notice:

Neither DocumentBase, nor ElementBase should be required to be abstract (we should have the option to mark them as abstract if needed)
The DbContext should know nothing about these base classes except their properties (as if they were declared in the concrete classes)
The only commonality between various entities will converge at ConcreteEntity > ConcreteEntityBase > EntityBase. No other paths need to be considered

The resulting tables should have the following declarations WITHOUT a discriminator column (no TPH, TPT):
Tables:

Document (Id, IsAuditable, DateTimeCreated, DateTimeModified, Name, Elements)
Element (Id, IsAuditable, DateTimeCreated, DateTimeModified, Name, Document, DocumentId)

The best resource I found was this blog discussing Table per Concrete Type (TPC), but it is over a decade old, while I am trying to make sense of EF Core 9.
Please note that this question is not about design choices or whether my approach aligns with best practices. I simply want to know whether this can be achieved with EF9 and, if so, what configuration is needed.

ElementBase should be abstract. Do you really want to allow new ElementBase()? It also doesn't really need a generic parameter, since it doesn't use it for anything. Though if you never obtain a EntityTypeBuilder<ElementBase> then it shouldn't be mapped as part of a heirachy.

@JeremyLakeman: I agree with you considering that the code posted is question-specific. In my case, XxxBase classes would be instantiated, but not in the context of the ORM. I also agree with anyone who thinks that not marking the classes as abstract (i.e. embedding extra functionality in them) is a questionable design choice.

As for generics, I write code generators where generics prove to be indispensable in certain scenarios. So once again, I agree that I should have left them out of the posted code. I included them since I did not know if they would be relevant to the ORM mapping strategy. It seems not to be the case.

You shouldn't need to define any inheritance configuration for EF to do what you expect, so long as you don't have any DbSet or entity configuration declared for the base class. Any explicit configuration you might need (data types, column naming, etc.) simply do through the end sub-classes, not the common base class.
I have similar base classes for my projects for "Editable" entities which centralizes common fields like CreatedByUserId, CreatedDateTime, etc. The base EnditableEntity does not have a table or any configuration, all configuration is based on the sub-classes. In my case the EditableEntity is abstract as it pretty much should be, but I don't think that directly affects the mapping. What likely would interfere with mapping and have EF expecting a TPH/TPT/TPC config would be any configuration or DbSet referencing the base class directly.

Thank you! It is a relief to know that no extra configuration is required as long as the base classes are not referenced in the context and/or via navigational properties. I have to ask, though, if you know of any sources that document this behavior as EF has evolved a lot and I could not find any recent and specific documentation on the same.

For general documentation for EF, MS's LearnEF site is quite good. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli) Specifically about this configuration I don't know of a specific doc around basic inheritance. The docs are about mapping specific inheritance structures It's basically TPC without explicit configuration. The difference with TPC is accommodating something like a relationship between another entity and any of the subclasses through their base type. (I.e. EntityTypeBase Something {get; set;} // which could reference Document or Element)

Both this and TPC would just have a Document and Element table, but relationships have to be specific to Documents or Elements, not the base class. That is where TPC would be needed, and supported since EF Core 7.
